# ¿Qué hace exactamente la última línea de código?

Tags: php, sql

**¿Qué hace exactamente la última línea de código?**

```
$c = executa($servidor, $usuari, $contrasenya, $bd,"
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Missatges
");

$row = $c->fetch_assoc();

$total = $row["COUNT(*)"];
```

Comment: Estás realizando una consulta **SQL** en **PHP** a la tabla `Missatges`y estás contando todos los registros (mensajes) qué hay. Al no definir un alias en el `COUNT(*)` el nombre para rescatarlo luego es el mismo `COUNT(*)`, pero podáis haber hecho algo como `COUNT(*) AS total` y rescatarlo como `$row["total"]`.

Answer (score -1):

Plantealo asi:

```
        $c = executa($servidor, $usuari, $contrasenya, $bd,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM Missatges");

        $total = $c->fetch_assoc()["TOTAL"];//selecciona una columna especifica del set de resultados
```

Espero te sriva!

Answer (score -1):

Lo que estas haciendo en la última línea es acceder al valor correspondiente a la columna llamada COUNT(*) devuelta por la consulta SQL, puedes indicar un nombre mas apropiado usando AS por ejemplo:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM Missatges`

De este modo se llamaría **TOTAL** en lugar de **COUNT(*)**.